# internal linking to posts does not exist, jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid, html-proofer

I ran htmlproofer and got this failure.

> internally linking to /posts/title, which does not exist

how do I fix the liquid tags in jekyll so that the HTML outputs correctly when built?

I think it has something to do with this line in `index.html`

```
<a href="{{ post.url | relative_url }}" title="{{ post.title }}"></a>
```

when I add `{{ post }}` in this line

`<a href="{{ post.url | relative_url }}{{ post }}" title="{{ post.title }}">`

the posts *at least* show on the `index.html`, even though it makes the site look broken. When `{{ post }}` is removed the main page looks normal, but when clicking on posts they lead to a 404...

Comment: repository url please.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/mrjules/chalked5

Answer (score 3):

HTMLProofer should check the generated site located at `_site` directory. This folder contains the generated files of your websites that has been processed by Jekyll, that way the failing links would be checked properly by htmlproofer.

For example:

```
htmlproofer --check-html \
        --internal-domains localhost:4000 \
        --assume-extension \
        --disable-external \
        _site
```

Comment: try with `<a href="{{ post.url | absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>` and setting in `_config.yml` the property: baseurl="" – or `<a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a>`

Comment: What is the generated url that leads to a 404 page?

Comment: example.com/projectname/year/month/title or https://mrjules.gitlab.io/chalked5/2016/10/configuring-chalk. I can't open blog posts from `index.html`

Comment: just downloaded your website and works for me, is the CI failing? it looks like there is some problem with permalinks (as it is published now, if you add `.html` to your blog posts it works, but it shouldn't be necessary)

Comment: in my `_config.yml` permalinks was set to `permalink: /:year/:month/:slug`. I changed it to `permalink: /:year/:month/:title.html` and now the posts open. My about page doesn't seem to generate `.html` even when adding `permalink: /:title.html` to the about page.

Comment: Solved my about page issue. Thanks marcanuy. If you didn't point out the `.html` permalink, I would have never thought to check my permalink setting in `_config.yml`